# Installing PCL on mint

Tags: installation, linux-mint, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to install PCL in linux mint 19  using PPA.

I executed the following command,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl
```

Unfortunately, it says that Cannot add `PPA: ''This PPA does not support bionic''.`

Is there any other workaround for the same apart from installing from source?

Answer (score 1):

Your Mint is basically Ubuntu 18.04.
In Ubuntu, you can install it via

```
sudo apt install libpcl-dev
```